# Is there some thing wrong with the way i write my while loops

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

Why are my while loops not working? I m getting no error, but also no output.

Codes are working perfectly fine uptil the main logic.

example my output for binary search is :
Enter the array size:
5

Enter array elements in sorted form :
1 2 3 4 5
Enter the target element: 2

//no output is shown after this user input
(NOTE: Same logics are perrfectly working with for loops)

//Code for Binary search (while loop not working )

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define max 20
int main(){

    int a[max],n,i,target;
    int l=0;
    int r=n-1;
    int mid=(l+r)/2;

    printf("\nEnter the array size: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("\nEnter array elements in sorted form : \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter the target element: ");
    scanf("%d",&target);

while(l<=r){
    
        if(target==a[mid]){
            printf("Element found at %d position",i+1);

        }
        else if(target<a[mid]){
            r=mid-1;
        }
        else{
            l=mid+1;
        }
    
}

return 0;
}
```

//Same problem with linear search while loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define max 20
int main(){

    int array[max],target,size,i=0,flag=0;
    printf("Enter the size of array: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("Enter the elements of array: ");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter the element to be found in array: ");
    scanf("%d",&target);

    printf("Target accepted");

   while( i < size ) {
      if(array[i]==target){
        printf("Element found at %d position",i+1);
        flag=1;
        break;
      }
      else{
        flag=0;
      }
      i++;
   }
    if(flag==0){
        printf("Element not found !!!");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, in the second case, you don't reset `i` after the `for` loop; so, because that loop ends when `i == size`, the `while` condition will never be true.

Comment: In the first example, n is uninitialized, so you're initializing r and mid to random values. In the second, i == size when you get to the while() loop as a result of the prior for() loop.

Comment: In your first example, you always print value `i+1` when you found the value. Should probably be `mid+1`, no? And also in first example you don't assign a value to `r` **after** reading `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the while (l<=r) loop, either 'l' or 'r' value is changed, but mid is never changed, thus if(target==a[mid]) will always false.

You need to change 'mid' value in the while loop.

Comment: True, but r and mid are garbage at that point. UB.

Answer (score 1):

First you were initializing the right index before getting the size of the array so you will never enter the while loop. Second thing is that you should set the middle element inside your while loop so it can update properly every time you change the left and right variables.
check the code below:

```
int a[max],n,i,target;
    int l=0;

    printf("\nEnter the array size: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int r=n-1;

    printf("\nEnter array elements in sorted form : \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter the target element: ");
    scanf("%d",&target);

    while(l<=r){
    
        int mid=(l+r)/2;
        if(target==a[mid]){
            printf("Element found at %d position",mid);
            break;
        }
        else if(target<a[mid]){
            r=mid-1;
        }
        else{
            l=mid+1;
        }
```